# What to write in a motivation letter where the template says "In a few lines, specify your professional project"

Tags: application, statement-of-purpose, france

My program is structured such that I have to do two years at one institution, then transfer to a different institution for the third and final year. I am now finishing the second year and filling out the application to transfer.

This application requires a motivation letter, for which the university provides a template. The template states the following:

> - Pursuit of studies envisaged beyond this degree
> - Reason for choosing this university
> - In a few lines, specify your professional project

For the last one, should I talk about my 2nd year end of studies project? This is my fist time writing a motivation letter.

Comment: Some clarifications in the comments have been edited into the main post. Also: this is technically undergraduate admissions, which we consider "off topic," but I won't mod-hammer this one since this seems essentially similar to a graduate application.

Comment: I assume these instructions were translated from French. Was the original "projet professionnel"? "Projet professionnel" seems to be a term of art in French in a way that "professional project" is not in English. See for example [here](https://www.avisto.com/fr/projet-professionnel/). Indeed, the word "projet" is a bit of a "faux ami"; a better translation would be "plan" or "goal."

Comment: nope, I copied the instructions as it is from the file. while yes most programs in France are in french the one I am applying to is in English and fully online meaning I don't have to move to France to take the classes. as for the finals for each semester I will take them at university in my city has a partnership with the one in France and in the end, students will receive a double diploma one from the university in their city since this program support other countries and one from the French university

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be defining "project" in the sense of your long term career goals, not a short term academic project.

So, write instead about what you envision for a career. And, perhaps, focus on how university studies will get you on the path to those long term goals.

If you want to write about your end of studies project only do so in response to how this university might support you in extensions of it if you see that as a path to publication or another goal.

But think more broadly and long term for the third part. The word "project" can have a lot of meanings.

Comment: I thought the same about what they meant with project. But there already two previous questions one about "studies envisaged beyond this degree" and the other "Reason for choosing this university" . I thought since this program is focus on e-learning and my final project was also about e-learning that my give me some extra points

Comment: Actually, the three questions are, I think, intended to cover the ground, not focus. The further studies question is about just that (grad/professional school, nothing...). The why question is to explore the immediate term goals and values. But the project question is for the long term. Why = near term. Studies = medium term. Project = long term. This seems to fit normal patterns.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. from my understanding here's what I did: in the 1st question, I talked about my interest in the field and my intention to pursue a master's and a Ph.D.. in the 2nd question I talked about my interest in the university's programs especially those that are online (e-learning), as for the 3rd question I am going to talk about my intention to pursue a PhD and become a college professor to share my knowledge with other students since I am not really interested in working for a company. does this look good?

Answer (score 0):

> specify your professional project

The prompt is not clear. My best guess would be along the lines of what Buffy wrote, but it would be reasonable to ask the university for clarification.

> [the institution is in France, but the instructions were in English]

Ah ha! This French-speaking institution probably mistranslated the phrase "projet professionnel." A better translation would have been "professional goals." A full definition is provided (in French) [here](https://www.avisto.com/fr/projet-professionnel/), but the gist of it is that they want a (brief) [statement of purpose](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statement-of-purpose): what are your professional goals, how will you achieve them, and how does your application here tie into those goals.

Comment: I searched for it in french and what I understand from it is that it's like a standard university motivation letter where I have to talk about what diploma I have, my interest in the program, and future goals if I get accepted, right?

Comment: Indeed. With an emphasis on the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not be focussing on the 2nd year of your degree.  Instead, you should follow their instruction to focus on "[p]ursuit of studies envisaged beyond this degree".  Comment on what you hope to do beyond this degree, your reason for choosing this university for your present program, and how this feeds into your overall professional goal.